# Timeout on recvfrom ( winsock2 & udp )

Tags: c++, c, udp, winsock2

I'm trying to implement a `timeout` on the `recvfrom()` function.

To do so, I use the `select()` function. I take the code from the great Internet, but don't know why, my program crash when I use it.
I launch this server in athread if that coudl help.
Here's what I try to do :

```
...
        // Setup timeval variable
        timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 5;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        // Setup fd_set structure
        fd_set fds;
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(id_de_la_socket, &fds);

        // Return value:
        // -1: error occurred
        // 0: timed out
        // > 0: data ready to be read
        int retval = select(id_de_la_socket+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if(retval == -1){
            printf("Error");
            return NULL;
        }
        else if(retval == 0){
            printf("Timeout");
            return NULL;
        }
        else{
            nombre_de_caractere=recvfrom(id_de_la_socket,buffer,1515,/*MSG_PARTIAL*/0,(struct sockaddr*)&information_sur_la_source,&tempo);
...
```

Before trying to implement the `timeout`, everything works fine, my `recvfrom()` was in block mode. So I think the problem come from this code that I add. Maybe it's a parameter of a function that I don't understand well.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : Full code :

```
#include "serveur.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
serveur::serveur()
{
}

StructureSupervision::T_StructureSupervision* serveur::receiveDataUDP(){
    WSADATA initialisation_win32;
    int erreur; 
    int tempo; 
    int nombre_de_caractere; 
    char buffer[65535]; 
    SOCKET id_de_la_socket; 
    SOCKADDR_IN information_sur_la_source; 

    erreur=WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&initialisation_win32);
    if (erreur!=0)
        printf("\nDesole, je ne peux pas initialiser Winsock du a l'erreur : %d %d",erreur,WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\nWSAStartup  : OK");


    id_de_la_socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if (id_de_la_socket==INVALID_SOCKET)
        printf("\nDesole, je ne peux pas creer la socket du a l'erreur : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\nsocket      : OK");


    information_sur_la_source.sin_family=AF_INET;
    information_sur_la_source.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.100.13.129"); // Ecoute sur toutes les IP locales
    information_sur_la_source.sin_port=htons(4000); // Ecoute sur le port 4000
    erreur=bind(id_de_la_socket,(struct sockaddr*)&information_sur_la_source,sizeof(information_sur_la_source));
    if (erreur!=0)
        printf("\nDesole, je ne peux pas ecouter ce port : %d %d",erreur,WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\nbind        : OK \n");


    tempo=sizeof(information_sur_la_source); // Passe par une variable afin d'utiliser un pointeur

    // Setup timeval variable
    timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 5;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    // Setup fd_set structure
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(id_de_la_socket, &fds);
    // Return value:
    // -1: error occurred
    // 0: timed out
    // > 0: data ready to be read
    ULONG NonBlock = 1; ioctlsocket(id_de_la_socket, FIONBIO, &NonBlock);
    int retval = select(id_de_la_socket+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if(retval == -1){
        printf("Error");
        return NULL;
    }
    else if(retval == 0){
        printf("Timeout");
        return NULL;
    }
    else{
    nombre_de_caractere=recvfrom(id_de_la_socket,buffer,1515,/*MSG_PARTIAL*/0,(struct sockaddr*)&information_sur_la_source,&tempo);
    buffer[nombre_de_caractere]=0; // Permet de fermer le tableau apr�s le contenu des data, car la fonction recvfrom ne le fait pas
    //printf("\nVoici les donnees : %s",buffer);
    StructureSupervision::T_StructureSupervision *structureReception = (StructureSupervision::T_StructureSupervision *) buffer;
    std::cout << "Voici le numero de Statut Ground Flight : " << structureReception->SystemData._statutGroundFlight;


    erreur=closesocket(id_de_la_socket);
    if (erreur!=0)
        printf("\nDesole, je ne peux pas liberer la socket du a l'erreur : %d %d",erreur,WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\nclosesocket : OK");

    // ********************************************************
    // Quitte proprement le winsock ouvert avec la commande WSAStartup
    // ********************************************************
    erreur=WSACleanup(); // A appeler autant de fois qu'il a �t� ouvert.
    if (erreur!=0)
        printf("\nDesole, je ne peux pas liberer winsock du a l'erreur : %d %d",erreur,WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\nWSACleanup  : OK");

    return structureReception;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't check if `select` return -1. Add something like `int retval = select(...) ;` and look at errno if `retval == -1`, like in the man example: http://linux.die.net/man/2/select

Comment: Done but didn't change anything, I will update my post

Comment: Did you set non-blocking mode on the socket?

Comment: @Holt Well no, why should I do this ?

Comment: Not a pro on `select`, but looking at google examples with socket I found this http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancediomethod5a.html, a bit disgusting but using non-blocking socket so just wondering if it could be the reason of the crashes. Maybe you should check and see what happens.

Comment: Where does it crash? How is `buffer` declared?

Comment: @unwind buffer[nombre_de_caractere]=0;

Comment: @EvansBelloeil Okay, so what is the value of `nombre_de_caractere` before the call to `recvfrom()`? You replace that value with the return value of `recvfrom()`, which is a bit scary-sounding.

Comment: @unwind No value before, it's initialisation, but it works well without the timeout ...

Comment: @Holt Using non block mode doesn't seems good to me, I'm afraid of losing infos :/

Comment: @EvansBelloeil So you have e.g. `int nombre_de_caractere; char buffer[nombre_de_caractere] = 0;`? If so, can you spot a problem there?

Comment: @unwind Well no, if it goes in the else, nombre_de_caractere is forced to be > 0.

Comment: @EvansBelloeil Why would you lose info with non blocking mode?

Comment: @Holt Yeah maybe, do you know how to put your socket in non blocking mode ?

Comment: On Windows, according to my previous link, I think: `ULONG NonBlock = 1; ioctlsocket(ListenSocket, FIONBIO, &NonBlock);` and check the return of `ioctlsocket` with SOCKET_ERROR for error.

Comment: You should initialize the tempo variable.

Comment: In a previous comment your wrote "No value before" to the question "What's the value of `nombre_de_charactere` before the call to `recvfrom`?" This number is important for the allocation of the `buffer`. When there is a undefined value you have undefined behavior. Your version without `select` just works by chance. `nombre_de-charactere` MUST be 1515 or above. If this is not fulfilled you can get a buffer overrun.

Comment: I will update my post right now, by giving my full code of server, and explaining that I launch it in a thread.

Comment: Ok I figured out what's wrong, the problem is that I call this function in a while(1) loop and I don't close the port correctly, I will answer my post soon, thanks every one, your comment make me think twice :)

Comment: @EvansBelloeil this id_de_la_socket thing... select() expects int type there, and id_de_la_socket is declared as SOCKET type.. not sure if this is a problem, but just to double-check...

Comment: Why  open and close a socket every time this method is called? You should keep the socket open for the life of the application. Your way you have a major risk of losing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, the problem was : This program runs in a loop, so I was opening and closing the socket at the wrong time.